# Y axis range in XYChart

Tags: javafx-2

[image]

[image]

I have a scaling problem with XYChart plotting: my data serie ranges in float values from 0.4 and 0.5 and when plotted on a scene I get as minimum Y value 1, so I can't see anything plotted.

This problem does not arise if I use data serie with higher values such as > 100

How can I set y axis according to data serie value used?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in JavaDoc for NumberAxis constructor: `public NumberAxis(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double tickUnit)` -- you can provide bottom and lower bounds for your axis.

```
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("X-Axis", 0d, 1d, .05);
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Y-Axis", 0d, 1d, .05);
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new ScatterChart.Series("Series 1", FXCollections.<ScatterChart.Data>observableArrayList(
            new XYChart.Data(.1, .1),
            new XYChart.Data(.2, .2))));
    ScatterChart chart = new ScatterChart(xAxis, yAxis, data);
    root.getChildren().add(chart);
```

**Update**: Autoranging of the chart works for me as well, see next code and screenshot. You may want to upgrade to JavaFX 2.1 or newer.

```
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new ScatterChart.Series("Series 1", FXCollections.<ScatterChart.Data>observableArrayList(
            new XYChart.Data(.01, .1),
            new XYChart.Data(.1, .11),
            new XYChart.Data(.12, .12),
            new XYChart.Data(.18, .15),
            new XYChart.Data(.2, .2))));
    XYChart chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis, data);
    root.getChildren().add(chart);
```

[image: linechart]

Comment: Thank you Sergey for your kind reply: what I would like to accomplish is to automatically set my Y range according to data set, i.e. I do not want to set Y axys every time I change dataset.
So, for instance, I use a dataset ranging from 0.4 and 0.5 my scene plot should display min and max within these values (but a fixed % , 2%, for min and max space on Y), and the same should do if I use a dataset ranging from 100 up to 1500

Comment: Very good thanks a lot I was looking for this answer long time :)

Comment: @Albertoacepsut, have you managed to add that +/- 2%? I'm trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: +1 for mentioning auto-ranging of axes. Was trying to reinvent that wheel myself until I stumbled into your answer.